# chi2 probability

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-function, chi-squared

I am trying to use this equation

$Prob_d(\chi^2 > \chi_0^2) = \frac{2} {2^{d/2} \Gamma(d/2)} \int_{\chi_0}^{\inf} x^{d-1}e^{-x^2/2} dx$

to compute probabilities of an empirical distribution $\chi^2_0$ ($d$ degrees of freedom). The equation is from Taylor 1997: *An Introduction to Error Analysis*.

(How) Is this expression related to the $\chi^2$ cumulative density distribution?

$p=\frac{1}{2^{d/2} \Gamma(d/2)}\int_{0}^{x}t^{d/2-1}e^{-t/2}dt$

Can I use available numerical implementations of the $\chi^2$ CDF to compute the former?

Comment: I suppose there is a change of variable $t = x^2$ going on. Note that $dt = dx^2 = 2dx$. Put the 2 in front of the integral. The $\exp$ function is pretty strightforward. Then $t^{d/2-1} = t^{d/2}/t = x^d/x^2 = x^{d-2}$ which differs. So I would check the book again on this. Maybe that's a typo?

Comment: @Quertiopler You are correct about the change of variable, but there is no typo in the book.  Your comment inspired my answer below, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation can be transformed using a substitution.

Write the first equation as $$P = \frac{2} {2^{d/2} \Gamma(d/2)} \int_{\chi_0}^{\infty} x^{d-1}e^{-x^2/2} dx$$

Define $t=x^2$, so $dt=2xdx =2t^{1/2}dx$

And so $dx=\frac{1}{2}t^{-1/2}dt$

Substituting we obtain $$P = \frac{2} {2^{d/2} \Gamma(d/2)} \int_{\chi_0^2}^{\infty} {(t^{1/2})}^{d-1}e^{-t/2}. \frac{1}{2}t^{-1/2}dt$$

Combining exponents of $t$ and taking the $1/2$ out we obtain

$$P=\frac{1}{2^{d/2} \Gamma(d/2)}\int_{\chi_0^2}^{\infty}t^{d/2-1}e^{-t/2}dt$$

as expected.

I am not sure however if I have treated the integration limits correctly.